Invoking script using launchd on MacOS is not working
Issue
I have a requirement to monitor a particular folder in Users/<user name>/Libraries/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. I have written a script that should be run all the time in the background to monitor the folder. I seem to have a permission issue when we are trying to access anything in Users/ from a launched
What I have tried?
I tried to set up a launch daemon that invokes a particular script by following steps mentioned in this Apple forum discussion.
Script
logger 'Hello Cruel World!'

The script is saved in the path - /usr/local/bin/greetings.sh
launchd plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>com.example.hello</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
 <string>/usr/local/bin/greetings.sh</string>
 </array>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

The plist is saved in the path - /Library/LaunchDaemons
Commands executed to load the launchd and provide permissions

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/greetings.sh -> To make the script
executable and give root level permissions.
sudo launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.hello.plist
sudo launchctl start com.example.hello

On printing the logs via log show —predicate 'process == "logger"' —info | grep "Hello Cruel World", I could see the Hello Cruel World getting printed.
Findings
In my initial investigation, I suspect the issue might lie in the permissions that the script has.
When the script is in /usr/local/bin ->
ls -l /usr/local/bin/greetings.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  <Date> /usr/local/bin/greetings.sh

When the script is in /Users/<user_name>/Desktop ->
/Users/<user>/Desktop/greetings.sh
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  staff  40 <date> /Users/<user>/Desktop/greetings.sh

The difference is between staff and wheel level permissions.
Question
Is there something that I am missing to do explicitly to grant the script the appropriate permissions to a script in location Users/<user> that performs operations like CRUD on a file? As per my understanding sudo permissions should do the job.

Have you tried changing the group for the script when it is resident in the Users directory? Try "sudo chgrp wheel  /Users//Desktop/greetings.sh".  Normally permissions are: owner: root Group: wheel .

@M.Rizzo Thanks for the comment. The script is still not getting invoked.

Did you update your plist file to have the right location in the ProgramArguments String?  You did change it from usr/local/bin ?

Why would you save a system script in a non-system location? I suspect you'd need to grant something (launchd?) explicit read access to the user's Desktop; but why would you want to run a script from there in the first place?

@M.Rizzo yes, did that

@tripleee I can move the script to /usr/bin, but I still would need to access certain files in Desktop as per my requirement. How to grant the explicit read access?

You should definitely leave /usr/bin alone; this is reserved for OS-installed utilities. You can put your own binaries in /usr/local/bin and required data files in /usr/share/lib or etc.

@tripleee Sure, but the data files are present in Users/.... directory. I don't think so with my current permission set, any of my script will be able to access any file on Users/.....

That's exactly why I keep suggesting to put them elsewhere.

I am afraid, we cannot do anything about it. We are trying to monitor the log files captured by Xcode[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode] which is by default stored in Users/<user_name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.

launchd plist should be formatted as XML.

Go to System Settings / Privacy & Security / Full Disk Access and grant the script access to the full disk.
I don't think the script's location matters, but many LaunchDaemons use /Library/Application Support/... for their executables.
On some Macs, I've had to await storage mounting, and so instead of directly executing the script, I resorted to executing sh with something like
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>sh</string>
                <string>-c</string>
                <string>while [ ! -x /Users/Shared/MyScript.sh ]; do echo StartWait; sleep 6; done; sleep 5; /Users/Shared/MyScript.sh arguments</string>
        </array>

